# Apache CXF doesn't select by http method when @DefaultMethod annotation is used

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I have two POST methods and one DELETE in my resource. They have same path.

I annotated one of POSTs with @DefaultMethod, so when someone doesn't send correct Accept header, correct method will be selected. But this causes that when DELETE is called, cxf selects POST instead of correct delete method. Is there any workaround for this?

CXF version: 3.1.17

```
@DefaultMethod
@POST
@Consumes(MeasurementMediaType.MEASUREMENT_TYPE)
@Produces(MeasurementMediaType.MEASUREMENT_TYPE)
public Response post(MeasurementRepresentation measurementRepresentation, @HeaderParam(value = HttpHeaders.ACCEPT) String acceptHeader) URISyntaxException {
    ...
}

@POST
@Consumes(MEASUREMENT_COLLECTION_TYPE)
@Produces(MEASUREMENT_COLLECTION_TYPE)
public Response post(MeasurementCollectionRepresentation measurementCollectionRepresentation, @HeaderParam(value = HttpHeaders.ACCEPT) String acceptHeader) {
 ...
   }


@DELETE
public Response delete(
        @QueryParam("fragmentType") String fragmentType,
        @QueryParam("source") String source,
        @QueryParam("dateFrom") DateTime dateFrom,
        @QueryParam("dateTo") DateTime dateTo,
        @QueryParam("type") String type) {
...
}

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cumulocity.measurement.rest.resources.MeasurementCollectionResource.post(MeasurementCollectionResource.java:280)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) DefaultMethod appears not to refer to the default method to select, but the default HTTPMethod.  So it's essentially overriding the httpmethod of your call.  This is a CXF extension to JAX-RS, so you may be able to ask the CXF team to update the functionality or create a new annotation for your use case.

2) If I understand you correctly, you would like the first method to be called if someone sends the body of {"Hello" : "World"}?  Wouldn't you then get errors when trying to construct your MeasurementRepresentation?  If they send a bad request, why not let CXF respond with an appropriate HTTP error code?

Comment: I want first method to be called when someone uses POST and doesn't specify Accept header with correct value. And still delete method called when DELETE http method is used. Temporary solved by own method comparator but then cxf is flooding logs with warnings `| WARN  Both com.rest.resources.MeasurementCollectionResource#post and com.rest.resources.MeasurementCollectionResource#post are equal candidates for handling the current request which can lead to unpredictable results`